# Multiple Conditions Check in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a Perl program.The program is simple.If the variables $a and $b are equal to 1 then something is to be printed.But the catch is the program has to check for the value of $b only if $var == 1. Otherwise,if $ $var == 0,only $a value has to be checked.

I have tried to write it by using nested if.But I am getting errors.(I tried to do it the same way how it can be done in C by using MACROS.)

```
my $var = 1 ;

my $a = 1 ;
my $b = 1 ;

if(($a == 1)
{
if($var == 1 )
{
&& ($b == 1)
}

)

print " hey ,it worked " ;

}
```

Case:1 ) So,$var==1 ,it has to check for the value of $b before printing.

```
my $var = 1 ;

my $a = 1 ;
my $b = 0 ;

if(($a == 1)
{
if($var == 1 )
{
&& ($b == 1)
}

)

print " hey ,it worked " ;

}
```

Case:2 ) $b==0,nothing gets printed.

```
my $var = 0 ;

my $a = 1 ;
my $b = 1 ;

if(($a == 1)
{
if($var == 1 )
{
&& ($b == 1)
}

)

print " hey ,it worked " ;

}
```

Case : 3 )$var==0,it shouldn't check for the value of $b and the line is printed.
I should get the above mentioned results.But I am not getting how to do it.Kindly Help.

Thanks for the replies.But you did not understand my question.What I really want to do is ,way back I had written a program in C where I will define the macro in .h file something like,

```
#define SWITCH 1
```

In .c file,I will check for the condition.

```
 if((a == 1)
#if SWITCH 
        && (b == 1)    
        )
       { 
        print " hey ,it worked " ; 
       }
```

So,here $b will be checked ,only if the macro value SWITCH is 1 in .h file.If the value is changed to 0,

```
#define SWITCH 0
```

then print statement depends only on the value of a and b value is not checked.I want to do the same thing in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This performs the check as you described it in English:

```
if ($var ? $a && $b : $a)
```

This is an equivalent check:

```
if ($a && ( !$var || $b ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have edited the question.please guide me

Comment: Perl doesn't have macros. If you need that level of optimization, you shouldn't be using Perl in the first place.

Comment: Yeah I know,but what is the closest way to implement this perl.Like using const SWITCH => 1 or something...

Comment: Can you tell me what the first check is doing? I dont know about ? : operator

Comment: This "?" and ":" is called the ternary operator and it is basically a "if...else" statement. In this case, `$var` value set the "if" expression.

Comment: Ouki is mistaken. `?:` is *a* ternary operator called the *conditional operator*. It's an if-then-else that can be used as follows: `my $x = condition() ? 4 : 5;`

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($a == 1) {
    if( ($var != 1) || ($var == 1 && $b == 1)  ) {
        say " hey ,it worked " ;
    }
}
```

Comment: One shouldn't use `== 0` and `== 1` to check for truth.

Comment: The `$var == 1 &&` is completely useless.

Comment: Agree, but OP does not say that he is checking for truth ( he might be checking numerical values ). And yes the statement is completely useless for a machine, but maybe not for a human? So I included it for readability

Comment: If you look at the comments and code, it's clear all three vars can only be 1 or 0. Even if you don't consider clear, it's almost certain, and thus an explanation (that you'd write different code if they were boolean) is in order.

Comment: How is `$var == 1 && $b == 1` more readable for a human than `$b == 1`?