# Nested if Statements in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a Perl program.The gist of the 
program is this:
There are two conditions.

Case:1 ) If cond1 = true and cond2 == true
then I will check whether $a=1 ,$b=1,$c=1 and $d=1.
If so, something is printed

```
    if(($cond1 eq true) && ($cond2 eq true))
    {
      if(($a=1) && ($b=1) && ($c=1) && ($d=1))
      {
        print " Hey,it worked" ;
      }
      else
     {
       print "Test case failed" ;
     }
   }
```

Case:2 ) If cond1=true and cond2=false
    then I have to check only for the variables a,b and c and not d.

```
if(($cond1 eq true) && ($cond2 eq false))
{
  if(($a=1) && ($b=1) && ($c=1))
  {
    print " Hey,it worked" ;
  }
  else
  {
    print "Test case failed" ;
  }
}
```

Case:3 ) If cond1=false  then I have to check only for 
    the variables a and b.

```
    if(($cond1 eq false))
    {
      if(($a=1) && ($b=1))
      {
        print " Hey,it worked" ;
      }
      else
     {
        print "Test case failed";
     }
   }
```

I have written it using nested if statements.But the program has become too lengthy.
Is there any effecient way to write the program using special operators in perl such that the code length is reduced.Kindly help.

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`, and your recent revisions to your question won't compile under those circumstances.

Comment: If you are going to keep editing your question, at least make it valid Perl. If you cannot be bothered with that, at the very least, fix the assignments in conditionals.

Comment: Is this question assumed to be written in Perl, or is it pseudocode?

Comment: @Matt Jacob It is just a pseudocode

Comment: Did you learn anything from answers to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43766887/100754

Comment: Can somebody out there upvote the question,I am not able to view the answers.You can downvote it later ,I will just copy the answers.

Comment: How does the negative score make the answers invisible to you?

Comment: Edit the answer to make it a good question. Mainly make a decent [mcve]. Then I and others will upvote without a need to downvote later.

Comment: Never mind, @ikegami s answer is known to you and I deleted mine (which is practically identical).

Answer (score 0):

- You have many assignments (e.g. `$a=1`) that should be comparisons (`$a==1`).
- Don't explicitly compare against `0` or `1` if you have booleans. Just check them for truth.
- `if (X) { if (Y) { ... } }` can be shrunk to `if (X && Y) { ... }`.
- You have too many parens.

In this case, you can use the following:

```
my $ok;
if ($a && $b) {
   if ($cond1)
      if ($cond2) {
         ++$ok if $c && $d;
      } else {
         ++$ok;
      }
   } else {
      ++$ok if !$cond2 && $c;
   }
}

say( $ok ? "worked" : "didn't work" );
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.I have edited the question.As per your 3rd point,I could nt shrink it since now it has a else condition

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect the changes to the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot ikegami.You are doing God's work ,I hope you know that:)